# AutoCompleteTextView delay

Tags: xml, kotlin, autocompletetextview

I have a problem with AutoCompleteTextView, after adding a custom style the typing is slow and it has some kind of delay. You can see my code here.

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/btnAddNewUser"
    style="@style/AppTheme.RoundedCornerMaterialTextViewLight"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:gravity="center|start"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:textColorHint="#8F8D8D"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llUserType" />
```